# Jump directly from one package body into another package body in PL/SQL developer

Tags: oracle, editor, plsqldeveloper

I'm using a trial version of PL/SQL developer 11.0.6.1796 and attempting to jump from package body **A** to package body **B** using a ctrl + click navigation.

Instead of jumping to the B package **body** - I'm taken to the B package **spec**.  Are there any switches/preferences available to indicate where in the entire package you want to jump or is this just unsupported?

Example functionality in Toad:
https://www.toadworld.com/products/sql-navigator/f/51/t/21833

Related SO question for SQL [SQLDeveloper jump between Package body and Package spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992003/sqldeveloper-jump-between-package-body-and-package-spec)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left Click goes to the package spec but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right Click goes to the package body.  It may even go to the beginning of the relevant package procedure or function.

Comment: Thanks @Jon!  I noticed that if I jump from package A while editing to package B it opens  in a "View Source" program window.  Any chance I could jump directly into an editable view, or am I just getting greedy?

Comment: Right-click on any object in the source code and select Edit.  PL/SQL Developer is full of little features like this but it's not always easy to find them.